# python - Return Text Between Parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have file contains several lines of strings written as :

```
[(W)40(indo)25(ws )20(XP)111(, )20(with )20(the )20(fragment )20(enlar)18(ged )20(for )20(clarity )20(on )20(Fig. )] TJ
```

I need the text inside the parentheses only. I try to use the following code :

```
import re

readstream = open ("E:\\New folder\\output5.txt","r").read()

stringExtract = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', readstream, re.DOTALL)
string = re.compile ('\(.*?\)')
stringExtract2 =  string.findall (str(stringExtract))
```

but some strings (or text) not exist in the output e.g, for the above string the word (with) not found in the output. Also the arrangement of strings differs from  the file, e.g,  for strings (enlar) and (ged ) above, the second one (ged ) appeared before (enlar), such as :  ( ged  other strings ..... enlar) How I can fix these problems?

Comment: Always use raw strings while stating patterns

Answer (score 7):

Without regexp:

```
[p.split(')')[0] for p in s.split('(') if ')' in p]
```

Output:

```
['W', 'indo', 'ws ', 'XP', ', ', 'with ', 'the ', 'fragment ', 'enlar', 'ged ', 'for ', 'clarity ', 'on ', 'Fig. ']
```

Comment: Sorry for digging this up, but what is the [0] for?

Comment: It gets the first element in the list returned by `p.split(')')`. So it takes eveything from the current "(" up to the next ")", and ignores whatever is outside the parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

findall looks like your friend here.  Don't you just want:

```
re.findall(r'\(.*?\)',readstream)
```

returns:

```
['(W)',
 '(indo)',
 '(ws )',
 '(XP)',
 '(, )',
 '(with )',
 '(the )',
 '(fragment )',
 '(enlar)',
 '(ged )',
 '(for )',
 '(clarity )',
 '(on )',
 '(Fig. )']
```

**Edit**:
as @vikramis showed, to remove the parens, use: `re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', readstream)`.  Also, note that it is common (but not requested here) to trim trailing whitespace with something like:

```
re.findall(r'\((.*?) *\)', readstream)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re

readstream = open ("E:\\New folder\\output5.txt","r").read()
stringExtract2 = re.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)', readstream)
```

#### Input:

```
readstream = r'[(W)40(indo)25(ws )20(XP)111(, )20(with )20(the )20(fragment )20(enlar)18(ged )20(for )20(clarity )20(on )20(Fig. )]'
```

#### Output:

```
['W', 'indo', 'ws ', 'XP', ', ', 'with ', 'the ', 'fragment ', 'enlar', 'ged ', 'for ', 'clarity ', 'on ', 'Fig. ']
```

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is

```
stringExtract = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', readstream, re.DOTALL)
```

I have no idea why you are doing this and im pretty sure you dont want to do this

try this instead

```
 readstream = "[(W)40(indo)25(ws )20(XP)111(, )20(with )20(the )20(fragment )20(enlar)18(ged )20(for )20(clarity )20(on )20(Fig. )] TJ"
 stringExtract = re.findall('\(([^)]+)\)', readstream, re.DOTALL)
```

which says find everything inside parenthesis that is not a closing parenthesis

Comment: this returns `(W,)` for me, not all text within parentheses in the string.